# Query object not working as expected?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

This code should be able to run on any AX system (change item & warehouse).  The issue is that CustInvoiceJour is not being returned sometimes.  What is odd, is if I just do a "select custInvoiceJour" with the same relations, it DOES find it?  How is this possible?

```
static void Job59(Args _args)
{
    CustInvoiceTrans            custInvoiceTrans;
    CustInvoiceJour             custInvoiceJour;
    InventTable             inventTable;
    QueryBuildRange             rangeItem;
    Query                       query;
    QueryBuildDataSource        qbds1;
    QueryBuildDataSource        qbds2;
    QueryBuildDataSource        qbds3;
    QueryRun                    qr;
    ;

    query = new Query();
    qbds1 = query.addDataSource(tablenum(CustInvoiceTrans));
    qbds2 = qbds1.addDataSource(tablenum(CustInvoiceJour));
    qbds2.relations(true);

    qbds2.addRange(fieldnum(CustInvoiceJour, SalesType)).value('!' + enum2str(SalesType::ReturnItem));
    rangeItem = qbds1.addRange(fieldnum(CustInvoiceTrans, ItemId));
    qbds1.addRange(fieldnum(CustInvoiceTrans, InvoiceDate)).value(queryRange(@'8/1/2011', @'8/31/2011'));
    qbds2.orderMode(OrderMode::OrderBy);
    qbds2.addOrderByField(fieldnum(CustInvoiceJour, DlvCountryRegionId));
    qbds2.addOrderByField(fieldnum(CustInvoiceJour, DlvState));
    qbds3 = qbds1.addDataSource(tablenum(InventDim));
    qbds3.relations(true);
    qbds3.joinMode(JoinMode::ExistsJoin);
    qbds3.addRange(fieldnum(InventDim, InventLocationId)).value(SysQuery::value('FG'));


    select firstonly inventTable
        where inventTable.ItemId    == '44831';

    info (strfmt("%1", inventTable.ItemId));
    rangeItem.value(inventTable.ItemId);

    qr = new QueryRun(query);
    while (qr.next())
    {
        custInvoiceTrans    = qr.get(tablenum(CustInvoiceTrans));
        custInvoiceJour     = qr.get(tablenum(CustInvoiceJour));

        if (!custInvoiceJour)
        {
            info ("Not found");
            select firstonly custInvoiceJour
                where custInvoiceJour.SalesId               == custInvoiceTrans.SalesId     &&
                      custInvoiceJour.InvoiceId             == custInvoiceTrans.InvoiceId   &&
                      custInvoiceJour.InvoiceDate           == custInvoiceTrans.InvoiceDate &&
                      custInvoiceJour.numberSequenceGroup   == custInvoiceTrans.numberSequenceGroup;
            if (custInvoiceJour)
                info("Found it");
        }
    }
}
```

The debugger shows these as the queries:

```
NAME:
    qbds1
VALUE:
    SELECT * FROM CustInvoiceTrans ORDER BY CustInvoiceJour.DlvCountryRegionId ASC, CustInvoiceJour.DlvState ASC WHERE ((ItemId = N'44831')) AND ((InvoiceDate>={ts '2011-08-01 00:00:00.000'} AND InvoiceDate<={ts '2011-08-31 00:00:00.000'})) EXISTS JOIN * FROM InventDim WHERE CustInvoiceTrans.InventDimId = InventDim.inventDimId AND ((InventLocationId = N'FG'))

NAME:
    qbds2
VALUE:
    SELECT * FROM CustInvoiceJour WHERE CustInvoiceTrans.SalesId = CustInvoiceJour.SalesId AND CustInvoiceTrans.InvoiceId = CustInvoiceJour.InvoiceId AND CustInvoiceTrans.InvoiceDate = CustInvoiceJour.InvoiceDate AND CustInvoiceTrans.numberSequenceGroup = CustInvoiceJour.numberSequenceGroup AND ((NOT (SalesType = 4)))


NAME:
    qbds3
VALUE:
    SELECT * FROM InventDim WHERE CustInvoiceTrans.InventDimId = InventDim.inventDimId AND ((InventLocationId = N'FG'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your qbds1 value doesn't show `JOIN * FROM CustInvoiceJour WHERE ...` (joined qbds2).

Add `qbds2.fetchMode(QueryFetchMode::One2One);` to your code and everything should be alright.

P.S. I would suggest to do it the other way round: CustInvoiceJour in qbds1, and CustInvoiceTrans in qbds2 (with default fetchMode), then you wouldn't have this problem at all.

Comment: I am actually fixing/debugging some pre-existing code.  I think the logic was that since we're searching for items on lines, to start with the lines.  What was strange is that the CustInvoiceJour was returned half of the time.  Thanks for this!